# LISP Interpreter (Bison and Flex Programming)

Tags: c, lisp, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to make a LISP interpreter using Bison and Flex Programming. I have most of the functionality needed, but, it only works for 2 numbers, i.e. (+ 2 2) or (* 2 2). I need it to work for more than 2, i.e. (+ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9). I would appreciate any help.

I have included my Bison and Flex files in addition to my C code and header file.

***LISP.y code***

```
%{
#include "lisptab.h"
%}

%union
{
   double dval;
   char *sval;
   struct ast_node *astNode;
   struct symbol_ast_node* symNode;
};

%token <sval> FUNC
%token <sval> TYPE
%token <sval> SYMBOL
%token <dval> NUMBER
%token LPAREN RPAREN EOL QUIT LET COND

%type <astNode> s_expr
%type <symNode> let_elem
%type <symNode> let_list

%%

program:/* empty */ {
                       printf("> ");
                    }
        | program s_expr EOL
          {
          //printf("yacc: program expr\n");
          printf("\n%lf", eval($2)->value);
          freeNode($2);
          printf("\n> ");
          }
          ;

s_expr:
        NUMBER
        {
          $$ = number($1);
        }

        | SYMBOL
        {
          $$ = symbol($1);
        }
        | LPAREN FUNC s_expr RPAREN
        {
          $$ = function($2, $3, 0);
        }
        | LPAREN FUNC s_expr s_expr RPAREN
        {
          $$ = function($2, $3, $4);
        }
        | LPAREN COND s_expr s_expr s_expr RPAREN
        {
          $$ = condition($3, $4, $5);
        }
        | LPAREN LPAREN LET let_list RPAREN s_expr RPAREN
        {
          $$ = let($4, $6);
        }
        | QUIT
        {
          exit(0);
        }

        | error
        {
        }
        ;

let_list:
        let_elem
        {
          $$ = let_list($1, NULL);
        }

        | let_list let_elem
        {
            $$ = let_list($2, $1);
        }
        ;

let_elem:
        LPAREN TYPE SYMBOL s_expr RPAREN
        {
          $$ = let_elem($2, $3, $4);
        }

        | LPAREN SYMBOL s_expr RPAREN
        {
          $$ = let_elem(NULL, $2, $3);
        }
        ;

%%
```

***LISP.l code***

```
%option noyywrap

%{
    #include "lisptab.h"
%}

digit [0-9]
number [+-]?{digit}+(\.{digit}+)?
func "neg"|"abs"|"+"|"-"|"*"|"div"|"^"|"max"|"min"|"hypot"|"print"|"EQ"|"LT"|"GT"|"GE"|"LE"|"NE"
type "integer"|"real"
quit "(stop)"
letter [a-zA-Z]
symbol {letter}+

%%

{number} {
                yylval.dval = strtod(yytext, NULL);
                //printf("lex: NUMBER dval = %lf\n", yylval.dval);
                return NUMBER;
            }

"let"       {
                //printf("lex: let\n");
                return LET;
            }

"(stop)"      {
                return QUIT;
            }
"cond"      {
                return COND;
            }

{func}      {
                yylval.sval = (char *) malloc(strlen(yytext)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(yylval.sval, yytext);
                //printf("lex: FUNC sval = %s\n", yylval.sval);
                return FUNC;
            }

{type}      {
                yylval.sval = (char *) malloc(strlen(yytext)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(yylval.sval, yytext);
                //printf("lex: TYPE sval = %s\n", yylval.sval);
                return TYPE;
            }

{symbol}    {
                yylval.sval = (char *) malloc(strlen(yytext)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(yylval.sval, yytext);
                //printf("lex: SYMBOL");
                return SYMBOL;
            }

"("         {
                //printf("lex: LPAREN\n");
                return LPAREN;
            }
")"         {
                //printf("lex: RPAREN\n");
                return RPAREN;
            }
"\n"        {
                //printf("lex: RPAREN\n");
                return EOL;
            }

[ \t]       ; /* skip whitespace */

.           // yyerror("lex: invalid character");

%%
```

**LISP.c**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lisptab.h"

SCOPE_NODE* currentScope;

int main(void)
{
  yyparse();
  return 0;
}

void yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

SYMBOL_TYPE getType(char *name)
{
  if (currentScope)
  {
    // make a new node to iterate through the table
    SCOPE_NODE* currScope = currentScope;
    SYMBOL_AST_NODE* currentSymbol = currScope->symbols;

    // start with current scope and work up through parents
    while(currScope)
    {
      while (currentSymbol)
      {
        //check to see if this is the symbol were looking for
        if (!strcmp(currentSymbol->name, name) && currentSymbol->type != INVALID) {
          return currentSymbol->type;
        }
        // otherwise keep on iterating
        currentSymbol = currentSymbol->next;
      }
      // move to the next scope and keep looking
      currScope = currScope->parent;
      if (currScope)
        currentSymbol = currScope->symbols;
      }
  }
  return INVALID;
}

SYMBOL_AST_NODE* getSymbol(char *name)
{
  SYMBOL_AST_NODE *result = NULL;
  int found = 0;

  // only check if there is an existing scope
  if (currentScope)
  {
    // make a new node to iterate through the table
    SCOPE_NODE* currScope = currentScope;
    SYMBOL_AST_NODE* currentSymbol = currScope->symbols;

    // start with current scope and work up through parents
    while(currScope)
    {
      while (currentSymbol)
      {
        //check to see if this is the symbol were looking for
        if (!strcmp(currentSymbol->name, name)) {
          result = currentSymbol;
          found = 1;
          break;
        }
        // otherwise keep on iterating
        currentSymbol = currentSymbol->next;
      }
      if (found) break;
      // move to the next scope and keep looking
      currScope = currScope->parent;
      if (currScope)
        currentSymbol = currScope->symbols;
      }
  }
  // throw error if its not found
  else if (!found) {
    printf("ERROR: Undeclared variable <%s> used\n", name);
    exit(1);
  }

  return result;
}

void leaveScope()
{
  if(currentScope)
    currentScope = currentScope->parent;
}

void enterScope(SCOPE_NODE* newScope)
{
  newScope->parent = currentScope;
  currentScope = newScope;
}

// find out which function it is
int resolveFunc(char *func)
{
  char *funcs[] = { "neg", "abs", "hypot", "+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "max", "min", "print", "EQ", "LT", "GT", "GE", "LE", "NE", ""};

  int i = 0;
  while (funcs[i][0] !='\0')
  {
    if (!strcmp(funcs[i], func))
      return i;

    i++;
  }
  yyerror("invalid function"); // paranoic -- should never happen
  return -1;
}

int resolveType(char* type)
{
  char *types[] = { "integer", "real" };

  int i = 0;
  while (types[i][0] != '\0')
  {
    if (!strcmp(types[i], type))
      return i;
    i++;
  }
  return -1;
}

// create a node for let
AST_NODE *let(SYMBOL_AST_NODE *symbols, AST_NODE *s_expr)
{
  AST_NODE *p;
  size_t nodeSize;

  // create a new scope node
  SCOPE_NODE *localScope = malloc(sizeof(SCOPE_NODE));
  localScope->symbols = symbols;

  // allocate space for the fixed size and the variable part (union)
  nodeSize = sizeof(AST_NODE) + sizeof(LET_AST_NODE);
  if ((p = malloc(nodeSize)) == NULL)
    yyerror("out of memory");

  // put scope and s_expr into the let node and return it
  p->type = LET_TYPE;
  p->data.let.scope = localScope;
  p->data.let.s_expr = s_expr;

  return p;
}

// add the new symbol to the list and return it
SYMBOL_AST_NODE* let_list(SYMBOL_AST_NODE *symbol, SYMBOL_AST_NODE *let_list)
{
  // insert the new symbol into the let_list
  SYMBOL_AST_NODE* current = let_list;
  int found = 0;

  // check for duplicates
  while (current)
  {
    if (!strcmp(symbol->name, current->name))
    {
      printf("ERROR: redeclaration of variable <%s> attempted\n", symbol->name);
      current->value = symbol->value;
      found = 1;
      symbol = let_list;
      break;
    }
    // keep looking through the list
    current = current->next;
  }

  // otherwise add it to the front of the list
  if (!found)
    symbol->next = let_list;

  // return the list with the new symbol
  return symbol;
}

// create a new symbol and return it
SYMBOL_AST_NODE *let_elem(char* type, char* symbol, AST_NODE *s_expr)
{
  SYMBOL_AST_NODE *p;
  size_t nodeSize;

  // allocate space the symbol
  nodeSize = sizeof(SYMBOL_AST_NODE);
  if ((p = malloc(nodeSize)) == NULL)
    yyerror("out of memory");

  if (type)
    p->type = resolveType(type);
  else
    p->type = INVALID;
  p->name = symbol;
  p->value = s_expr;
  return p;
}

// create a symbol node
AST_NODE *symbol(char* name)
{
  AST_NODE *p;
  size_t nodeSize;

  // allocate space for the fixed sie and the variable part (union)
  nodeSize = sizeof(AST_NODE) + sizeof(SYMBOL_AST_NODE);
  if ((p = malloc(nodeSize)) == NULL)
    yyerror("out of memory");

  p->type = SYM;
  p->data.symbol.name = name;
  return p;
}

// create a node for a number
AST_NODE *number(double value)
{
  AST_NODE *p;
  size_t nodeSize;

  // allocate space for the fixed sie and the variable part (union)
  nodeSize = sizeof(AST_NODE) + sizeof(NUMBER_AST_NODE);
  if ((p = malloc(nodeSize)) == NULL)
    yyerror("out of memory");

  p->type = NUM_TYPE;
  p->data.number.type = REAL;
  p->data.number.value = value;
  return p;
}

// create a node for a condition
AST_NODE *condition(AST_NODE* condition, AST_NODE* ifTrue, AST_NODE* ifFalse)
{
  AST_NODE *p;
  size_t nodeSize;

  // allocate space for the fixed sie and the variable part (union)
  nodeSize = sizeof(AST_NODE) + sizeof(COND_AST_NODE);
  if ((p = malloc(nodeSize)) == NULL)
    yyerror("out of memory");

  p->type = COND_TYPE;
  p->data.condition.condition = condition;
  p->data.condition.true_expr = ifTrue;
  p->data.condition.false_expr = ifFalse;

  return p;
}

// create a node for a function
AST_NODE *function(char *funcName, AST_NODE *op1, AST_NODE *op2)
{
  AST_NODE *p;
  size_t nodeSize;

  // allocate space for the fixed sie and the variable part (union)
  nodeSize = sizeof(AST_NODE) + sizeof(FUNCTION_AST_NODE);
  if ((p = malloc(nodeSize)) == NULL)
    yyerror("out of memory");

  p->type = FUNC_TYPE;
  p->data.function.name = funcName;
  p->data.function.op1 = op1;
  p->data.function.op2 = op2;

  return p;
}

// free a node
void freeNode(AST_NODE *p)
{
  if (!p)
    return;

  if (p->type == FUNC_TYPE)
  {
    free(p->data.function.name);
    freeNode(p->data.function.op1);
    freeNode(p->data.function.op2);
  }

  free (p);
}

NUMBER_AST_NODE* eval(AST_NODE *p)
{
  NUMBER_AST_NODE* result = malloc(sizeof(NUMBER_AST_NODE));
  NUMBER_AST_NODE* op1 = malloc(sizeof(NUMBER_AST_NODE));
  NUMBER_AST_NODE* op2 = malloc(sizeof(NUMBER_AST_NODE));

  if (!p)
    return result;

  else if (p->type == NUM_TYPE)
  {
    result = &p->data.number;
    result->value = result->type == INTEGER ? round(result->value) : result->value;
  }

  else if (p->type == FUNC_TYPE)
  {
    int funcType = resolveFunc(p->data.function.name);
    switch (funcType)
    {
      //unary instructions
      case NEG:
        result = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        result->value = -result->value;
        break;
      case ABS:
        result = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        result->value = fabs(result->value);
        break;

      //arithmetic operations
      case ADD:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);

        // set the new type and value
        result->type = ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) ? INTEGER : REAL;
        result->value = op1->value + op2->value;
        break;
      case SUB:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        if ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) {
          result->type = INTEGER;
          result->value = round(op1->value - op2->value);
        }
        else {
          result->type = REAL;
          result->value = op1->value - op2->value;
        }
        break;
      case MULT:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);

        // set the new type and value
        result->type = ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) ? INTEGER : REAL;
        result->value = op1->value * op2->value;
        break;
      case DIV:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);

        if ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) {
          result->type = INTEGER;
          result->value = round(op1->value / op2->value);
        }
        else {
          result->type = REAL;
          result->value = op1->value / op2->value;
        }
        break;

      // other binary operations
      case POW:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);

        result->type = ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) ? INTEGER : REAL;
        result->value = pow(op1->value, op2->value);
        result->value = result->type == INTEGER ? round(result->value) : result->value;
        break;
      case MAX:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) ? INTEGER : REAL;
        result->value = fmax(op1->value, op2->value);
        break;
      case MIN:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) ? INTEGER : REAL;
        result->value = fmin(op1->value, op2->value);
        break;
      case HYPOT:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = ((op1->type==INTEGER) && (op2->type==INTEGER)) ? INTEGER : REAL;
        result->value = hypot(op1->value, op1->value);
        break;
      case PRINT:
        result = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        if (result->type == INTEGER)
          printf("%d", (int)result->value);
        else printf("%.2lf", result->value);
        break;
      case EQUAL:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = INTEGER;
        result->value = op1->value == op2->value ? 1 : 0;
        break;
      case SMALLER:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = INTEGER;
        result->value = op1->value < op2->value ? 1 : 0;
        break;
      case LARGER:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = INTEGER;
        result->value = op1->value > op2->value ? 1 : 0;
        break;
      case GREATEREQUAL:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = INTEGER;
        result->value = op1->value >= op2->value ? 1 : 0;
        break;
      case LESSEQUAL:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = INTEGER;
        result->value = op1->value <= op2->value ? 1 : 0;
        break;
      case NOTEQUAL:
        op1 = eval(p->data.function.op1);
        op2 = eval(p->data.function.op2);
        result->type = INTEGER;
        result->value = op1->value != op2->value ? 1 : 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  // just evaluate the right side of each let
  else if (p->type == LET_TYPE)
  {
    //enter the new scope, evaluate, then leave
    enterScope(p->data.let.scope);
    result = eval(p->data.let.s_expr);
    leaveScope();
  }

  else if (p->type == SYM)
  {
    p->data.symbol = *getSymbol(p->data.symbol.name);
    // if there was no type declared
    // check with previously declared values
    if (p->data.symbol.type == INVALID)
      p->data.symbol.type = getType(p->data.symbol.name);
    // if theres still no type, error
    if (p->data.symbol.type == INVALID) {
      printf("ERROR: undeclared variable <%s> used\n", p->data.symbol.name);
      exit(1);
    }
    else {
      op1 = eval(p->data.symbol.value);
      if (p->data.symbol.type == INTEGER) {
        result->type = INTEGER;
        if (fmod(op1->value, 1) != 0)
          printf("WARNING: incompatible type assignment for variable <%s>\n", p->data.symbol.name);
        result->value = round(op1->value);
      }
      else {
        result->type = REAL;
        result->value = op1->value;
      }
    }
  }
  else if (p->type == COND_TYPE)
  {
    result = eval(p->data.condition.condition)->value ? eval(p->data.condition.true_expr) : eval(p->data.condition.false_expr);
  }

  return result;
}
```

***LISP.h***

```
#ifndef __lisp_h_
#define __lisp_h_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "y.tab.h"

int yyparse(void);
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);

typedef enum { INVALID=-1, INTEGER, REAL } SYMBOL_TYPE;
typedef enum { NUM_TYPE, FUNC_TYPE, LET_TYPE, SYM, COND_TYPE } AST_NODE_TYPE;
typedef enum { NEG = 0, ABS, HYPOT, ADD, SUB, MULT, DIV, POW, MAX, MIN, PRINT, EQUAL, SMALLER, LARGER, GREATEREQUAL, LESSEQUAL, NOTEQUAL } FUNC_NAMES;

typedef struct scope_node
{
   struct symbol_ast_node* symbols;
   struct scope_node* parent;
} SCOPE_NODE;

typedef struct
{
    SYMBOL_TYPE type;
    double value;
} NUMBER_AST_NODE;

typedef struct
{
    struct ast_node *condition;
    struct ast_node *true_expr;
    struct ast_node *false_expr;
} COND_AST_NODE;

typedef struct function_ast_node
{
   char *name;
   struct ast_node *op1;
   struct ast_node *op2;
} FUNCTION_AST_NODE;

typedef struct symbol_ast_node
{
   char* name;
   SYMBOL_TYPE type;
   struct ast_node* value;
   struct symbol_ast_node* next;
} SYMBOL_AST_NODE;

typedef struct let_ast_node
{
   SCOPE_NODE* scope;
   struct ast_node* s_expr;
} LET_AST_NODE;

typedef struct ast_node
{
   AST_NODE_TYPE type;
   union
   {
      NUMBER_AST_NODE number;
      FUNCTION_AST_NODE function;
      LET_AST_NODE let;
      SYMBOL_AST_NODE symbol;
      COND_AST_NODE condition;
   } data;
} AST_NODE;

// functions for creating ast_nodes
AST_NODE* number(double value);
AST_NODE* function(char *funcName, AST_NODE *op1, AST_NODE *op2);
AST_NODE* let(SYMBOL_AST_NODE *symbols, AST_NODE *s_expr);
SYMBOL_AST_NODE* let_list(SYMBOL_AST_NODE *symbol, SYMBOL_AST_NODE *let_list);
SYMBOL_AST_NODE* let_elem(char* type, char* symbol, AST_NODE* s_expr);
AST_NODE *condition(AST_NODE* condition, AST_NODE* ifTrue, AST_NODE* ifFalse);
AST_NODE* symbol(char *name);

// functions for doing stuff with the symbol table
double getSymbolValue(char* name);
void leaveScope();
void enterScope(SCOPE_NODE* newScope);

// functions for other stuff
NUMBER_AST_NODE* eval(AST_NODE *ast);
void freeNode(AST_NODE *p);

#endif
```

Comment: I attempted to make it work for more than 2 numbers, but when that did not work, I settled to initialize op1 and op2 to atleast get it to work. I would appreciate if you guys could help me modify it so I can get it to work for more than 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`LPAREN FUNC s_expr s_expr RPAREN` defines a function that takes exactly two arguments.  You could just define ones like this with more and more arguments, but that's not how you usually do it.

Instead you want to have a function take a list of s-expressions:

`s_expr_list:
  s_expr
| s_expr_list s_expr
;`

Then you just have `LPAREN FUNC s_expr_list RPAREN`